# how to Stop this Bash script from sending email to the Admin?

Tags: bash, email

i have this script on a cron job setup like this:

```
*/10 * * * * /bin/sh /home/scripts/restart_apache
```

And this is the script itself:

```
#!/bin/bash

cl=`awk '{print $1}' /proc/loadavg `
cll=`printf %.0f $cl`

echo $cll
if [ $cll -gt 100 ]
then
        /etc/init.d/apache restart
fi
```

This script is sending an email every 10 minutes, the question is:
How can i disable the email notification but retain the script functionality?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The email isn't coming from the script. `cron` sends email with any output, so the obvious solution should be to get rid of the output.

```
*/10 * * * * /bin/sh /home/scripts/restart_apache >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Hi i notice other cron jobs have >/dev/null 2>&1, what's the difference between >/dev/null 2>&a and >/dev/null 2>&1? if any.

Comment: @NicoBlog A typing error I'm guessing, should be `>/dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: @NicoBlog Yes, it was just a typo

Answer (score 2):

It actually is the cron daemon that sends the message, not that script.

You can generally turn off that feature of cron by simply adding a single line to your crontab: `MAILTO=""`. So your crontab would read like this:

```
MAILTO=""
*/10 * * * * /bin/sh /home/scripts/restart_apache
```

To find out about such things it *always* is a good idea to read a bit about the utilities you use. Typically the "linux man pages" offer a wealth of precise information. So have a try with `man 5 crontab` :-)

Comment: Thanks this is a valid option but it also disable all emails for all other cron jobs not the specific job i didn't want to be notified about. Still good to know.